# How to store a local copy of a dependency passed to a superclass without casting

Tags: java

Consider the following case with dependencies injected in constructors:

```
class Dependency extends AbstractDependency {
}

class Super {
    private final AbstractDependency dependency;

    public Super(AbstractDependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    protected AbstractDependency getDependency() {
        return dependency;
    }
}

class Sub {
    private final Dependency dependency;

    public Sub() {
        super(new Dependency(...));
        this.dependency = (Dependency)dependency;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is having the `Sub` methods able to use a concrete subclass of `AbstractDependency` without having to cast all the time.

My question: is there an elegant way of getting rid of the cast in the constructor of `Sub`? `super(dependency = new Dependency())` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off using a generic type, so you have don't have to keep duplicate references in the first place:

```
class Super<D extends AbstractDependency> {
    private final D dependency;
    //...
}

class Sub extends Super<Dependency> {
    public Sub() {
        super(new Dependency(...));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems like a pretty reasonable approach. It will mean scattering `<?>` liberally through my code whenever a reference doesn't care about this dependency: but that's probably a reasonable price to pay.

Comment: @sprinter If the wildcard bothers you, you can always create another subclass for `AbstractDependency`.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to use generics as @shmosel mentioned. If you dont want to use generics then I would avoid extending concrete class and would just use abstract method, which IMHO is much cleaner:

```
public abstract class Super {
    protected abstract AbstractDependency getDependency();
}

public class Sub {
    private final Dependency dependency;

    public Sub() {
        this.dependency = new Dependency();
    }

    protected AbstractDependency getDependency(){
        return dependency;
    }
}
```